# What is Google Web Driver in the Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android, web-testing

I see a list of optional items to install in the packages window, and can't find any reference to what the **Google Web Driver** and what it actually does?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Web Driver is selenium's framework for testing webapps on Android Device.

For more details on how you can use this visit the [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/10/introducing-android-webdriver.html)

Comment: referenced link seems broken can you please verify it ?

Answer (score 3):

Web Driver is still a good tool for testing web apps.

The Android Web App is another part of Selenium which is used for testing web apps on all platforms.

For a better understanding of how to use the Android Web App, you will need to learn Selenium. Settings for what needs to be configured differently in Android can be found on the Selenium site.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#android-driver